# Accessing a public text file by passing a key in Django

Tags: python, django, architecture

I am looking to host a text file that will be publicly accessible on a Django application:

```
http://www.example.com/textfile
```

However, when someone is accessing this text file, they need to to pass an access key, e.g

```
http://www.example.com/textfile?accesskey=123456
```

The access key is only known to members who are allowed access to this file. The reason for doing it this way is that I have a 3rd party legacy device that can only read text files, and I need to protect the file somehow.

Is it possible to run this in Django urls.py? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Use [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)? It has different types of views and permissions to access them.

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned this but is there anything more lightweight to achieve this. Seems a bit of an overkill to install DRF for this one text file.

Comment: so what did you attempt to do, it is really not that hard to write

Comment: Even if you don't use a third party library you'll have to protect your view with permissions - see [Using the Django Authentication System](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default). For restful endpoints there's a number of smaller modules such as [Restless](https://restless.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [Tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). – dmitryro 16 mins ago

Comment: For this simple use case, isn't the answer described below the best way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo code below could achieve something like this:

views.py:

```
def get_text(request):

    key = request.GET['accessKey']

    if key in VALID_KEYS: return FileResponse(file)

    else: return 404Response
```